# A linear map is an isomorphism if and only if the determinant is nonzero.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant

A linear map is an isomorphism if and only if the determinant is nonzero.

I would like to see a proof of this statement ?

Comment: This is just because a matrix is invertible if and only if $det\neq 0$

Comment: How do you define the determinant of a linear map? Via alternating $n$-forms? Or (yuk) by picking a basis and looking at matrices?

Comment: I'm trying to prove and show A linear map is an not isomorphism  if the determinant is zero, can any one show me a pooof ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be an $n$ dimensional $F-$vector space. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map, and $B$ a basis of $V$. Then let $A$ be the matrix for $T$ with respect to $B$. Then
$$A\, \mathrm{adj}(A) = \det(A)I_n$$
If $\det(A)$ is nonzero, then we see that $A$ is invertible, with $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}\mathrm{adj}(A)$. The above formula can be verified via direct computation, using the Laplace expansion to calculate the determinant.

Now suppose $\det(A) = 0$. If $A$ were invertible, then we would have $1=\det (I_n) = \det (AA^{-1}) = \det(A)\det(A^{-1}) = 0\cdot \det(A^{-1})=0$, which is impossible. Thus, $A$ is not invertible.

Now, one just needs to show that the determinant of $A$ is nonzero iff the determinant of $T$ is nonzero, and that $T^{-1}$ exists iff $A^{-1}$ exists.